# cannot access property of JSON object when dynamically built but can when statically built

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I've been at this for an hour and I need help. This is kind of baffling me. Consider this explicit setup of an object in my code:

**WORKING CASE:**

---

```
var terms={};
            terms[0]={}; 
            terms[1]={"label":"bag","cell_src":"images/bag.jpg","clue_type":"audio","clue_src":"/audio/bus.wav"};
            terms[2]={"label":"crayon","cell_src":"images/crayon.jpg","clue_type":"audio","clue_src":"/audio/car.wav"};
            terms[3]={"label":"pen","cell_src":"images/pen.jpg","clue_type":"audio","clue_src":"/audio/car.wav"};
            terms[4]={"label":"pencil","cell_src":"images/pencil.jpg","clue_src":"/audio/boat.wav"};
            terms[5]={"label":"pencil_case","cell_src":"images/pencil_case.jpg","clue_src":"/audio/train.wav"};
            terms[6]={"label":"rubber","cell_src":"images/rubber.jpg","clue_src":"/audio/taxi.wav"};
            terms[7]={"label":"ruler","cell_src":"images/ruler.jpg","clue_src":"/audio/plane.wav"};
            terms[8]={"label":"sharpener","cell_src":"images/sharpener.jpg","clue_src":"/audio/taxi.wav"}; 
           window.terms= terms;
window.terms= terms; // for using globaly
```

if I do a console.log(window.terms[1]); I get "bag". Thats what I want.

**NOT WORKING CASE**

---

If instead of explicitly defining the values of term{}, I read in the contents from a json file and assign them to each enumerated index like this:

```
var terms={};
terms[0]={};
$.getJSON('content.json', function(data){

  $.each(data,function(i){
    //terms[i]={"label":"bag","cell_src":"images/bag.jpg","clue_type":"audio","clue_src":"/audio/bus.wav"};
    terms[i+1]={"label":data[i].headword,"cell_src":data[i].image,"clue_type":"audio","clue_src":data[i].audio};

  });
  window.terms=terms;   
});
```

if I do a console.log(window.terms[1]); I get an error *"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined"* Note that I have an alternate attempt commented out where I eliminate the possibility that theres something weird going on with the values I am trying to pull in and I explicitly assign the same static value to all the indexes. That produces the same error.

Any ideas how this could be??

Answer (score 1):

`$.getJSON` does not block when performing an AJAX call. You have to keep the callback chain a live.

Comment: I can't see anything happening outside the ajax success callback.

Comment: Oops, the `console.log` is outside

Answer (score 1):

The `$.getJSON()` function is just a shorthand for a call to `$.ajax()` to load a JSON file. Since the AJAX call is asynchronous, the execution of `$.getJSON()` completes, and any code after it is executed, before the data has been loaded and stored in your variable.

If you want to work with `terms` do so inside the `success` callback function that you're passing to `$.getJSON()`.

If your code looks like this:

```
var terms={};
terms[0]={};
$.getJSON('content.json', function(data){

  $.each(data,function(i){
    //terms[i]={"label":"bag","cell_src":"images/bag.jpg","clue_type":"audio","clue_src":"/audio/bus.wav"};
    terms[i+1]={"label":data[i].headword,"cell_src":data[i].image,"clue_type":"audio","clue_src":data[i].audio};

  });
  window.terms=terms;   
});

// use window.terms here
```

Then it won't work, because the // use window.terms here part executes *before* the AJAX call has finished. You'll need to move that to a separate function and call that from the `success` callback:

```
function workWithTerms() {
    // use window.terms here
}

var terms={};
terms[0]={};
$.getJSON('content.json', function(data){

  $.each(data,function(i){
    //terms[i]={"label":"bag","cell_src":"images/bag.jpg","clue_type":"audio","clue_src":"/audio/bus.wav"};
    terms[i+1]={"label":data[i].headword,"cell_src":data[i].image,"clue_type":"audio","clue_src":data[i].audio};

  });
  window.terms=terms;   
  workWithTerms();
});
```

Comment: Same problem doing this:      $.getJSON('content.json').done(function(data){
                    var terms={};terms[0]={};
                    $.each(data,function(i){
                        //console.log(data[i].headword);
                        //terms[i]={"label":"bag","cell_src":"images/bag.jpg","clue_type":"audio","clue_src":"/audio/bus.wav"};
                        
                    });
                    window.terms=terms;
                });

Comment: I can't see anything happening outside the success callback.

Comment: Oops, the `console.log` is outside

Comment: @Nuevallorker What if you put `console.log(window.terms[1])` right after the `window.terms = terms;` line, so that's also inside the callback?

Comment: well that defeats the point of assigning the terms array to the window object. The window object is meant to be global so any properties or objects I attach to it are supposed to be accessible throughout the whole script. Unless i've misunderstood something?

Comment: They are accessible, but not before the callback runs. You can't cheat the time by escaping scopes.

Comment: @Nuevallorker The point is to illustrate *when* the `window.terms` variable gets populated. The moment you start using AJAX you need to structure your code differently. If you have logic immediately *after* the call to `$.getJSON()` (in the same function) then you'll need to move that to a separate function, and call that from the `success` callback.

Comment: though this is on the right track because if I do move the console.log to inside the success function, it outputs the value correctly. Clearly theres a scoping issue here but i'm not sure how to solve it. The window object is discarding the values once the function completes.

Comment: There's not a scoping issue. There's a timing issue.

Comment: Just because some variable is in the scope, it doesn't mean it's been assigned to.

Comment: @Nuevallorker It's not a scoping issue, it's an order of execution issue. The call to `$.getJSON()` fires off an AJAX call (which is asynchronous) and *immediately returns*, so any code after that (such as your `console.log`) will be executed. After that has happened the asynchronous request receives a response, triggering the execution of the `callback` function.

Comment: @JanDvorak not sure I understand. Even if I assign values to a global object? Isn't the point of using the global object to store those values so that I don't lose them?

Comment: @Nuevallorker not even global objects can be assigned to retroactively. If you read before you write, there's nothing there.

Comment: @Nuevallorker the code after an AJAX call executes before the AJAX callback executes. In fact, the code may execute before the AJAX request is _sent_.

Comment: If you feel the need to assign outwards, there's a great deal of chance you'll be dealing with timing issues.

Comment: Even with `$.each`, `$().each`, `[].map`... you are not supposed to rely on the execution order.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to define terms as an array of objects. Currently you have it defined as an object with properties 1, 2, 3, etc. Syntax like `var terms = {}` means `terms` is an object and when you assign `terms[1] = {"label": "bag"}` you're saying "the property named 1 of object terms is `{"label": "bag"}`. Just change your terms declaration to this:

```
var terms = [];
```

Also, if you want to see the label property of one of the objects the log statement would looks like this:

```
console.log(terms[2].label);
```

Comment: I've already got the rest of my program relying on this data structure and working perfectly so theres no good reason to change it considering the data structure in the non working example is identical (seemingly perhaps?)

Comment: I can't see how using an object instead of an array would cause the behavior observed.

Comment: It just seems as though you're treating terms as an array when it's actually declared at an object right now. As it stands, `terms[1]` is the same as saying `terms.1`, didn't know if you realized that.

Comment: @clav `terms.1` is invalid syntax. A property has to be a valid identifier name if it is to be used with the dot notation. However, `terms[1]` works for objects and arrays alike, and is actually equivalent to `terms['1']`

Comment: @JanDvorak, yes I know that, just an example to try to make things clear because it looked like there was confusion between object vs array. The fact that the ajax call returns before terms is defined is the base problem, as made clear by the `cannot read property 1 of undefined`.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your input. I understand what you've explained regarding the timing but I'm afraid i'm still not clear on how to solve it. Isn't using the .done() callback supposed to be used this way? Where should my assignment be placed then in order to achieve what I am trying to achieve?